# How to normalize vector to sum to 1?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create an array/vector such that all the values sum up to 1. I can't do this for some reason when I do the following:

```
s={{0.80555}, {0.503259}, {0.254974}, {0.18113}}
s/Total[s]
```

I get an error `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {{0.80555},{0.503259},{0.254974},{0.18113}} {0.573094} cannot be combined.`

How do I work around this? I tried Flatten[s]/Flatten[Total[s]] but that didn't work either.

Comment: s = Flatten[{{0.80555}, {0.503259}, {0.254974}, {0.18113}}];
s/Total[s]

Comment: Standard format for a vector would be `s = {0.80555, 0.503259, 0.254974, 0.18113};` Then you'd do `sN = Normalize[s,Total]`. If you want to keep the form you have you could do `sN = Transpose[Normalize[#,Total]&/@Transpose[s]]`

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use Normalize with a custom function:

```
s = {{0.80555}, {0.503259}, {0.254974}, {0.18113}};
s = Normalize[s, Total[#, \[Infinity]] &]
```

because this will not crash when the sum is 0:

```
s = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}
s = Normalize[s, Total[#, \[Infinity]] &]

s = {{2}, {0}, {-2}, {0}}
s = Normalize[s, Total[#, \[Infinity]] &]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the second argument to `Total` to specify the level in a list to total.

```
s / Total[s, 2]
(* {{0.461656}, {0.288415}, {0.146124}, {0.103805}} *)
```

To total all levels

```
s / Total[s, Infinity]
(* {{0.461656}, {0.288415}, {0.146124}, {0.103805}} *)
```